# Distance between two lines, passing through origin

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How could I find the distance between two lines if I want that distance to be measured through a point (such as the origin)? The two lines would be straight lines, such as x=20, y=-15. The solution would create a triangle shape once the distance is introduced.

My goal is to further this by finding a way to check different distances from other possible points on those lines, while keeping the distance through the origin as a straight line. I'd also like to be able to find the angle of that distance.

Basically, I want to rotate the hypotenuse on the origin to find different angles and triangle dimensions.

Comment: as I understand this you want to **define** distance from $A$ to $B$ as the straight line distance from $A$ to $(0,0)$ plus the straight line distance from $(0,0)$ to $B$

Comment: Yes, but that entire line should remain straight; it should not "bend" or "change angle" at the origin. One desired point on the line will always be in the 3rd quadrant, and the other will always be in the first quadrant. If it helps to imagine the problem, this all basically creates a triangle, where the base is one of the lines and the side is the other line; I want to find different lengths and angles of the hypotenuse that travel through the origin, thus cutting those original lines (such as x=20, y=-15) short at the corners of the triangle.

Comment: this is not the distance between two lines, rather the distance from a point $A$ in the third quadrant to a line, including the possibility of infinite distance

Comment: It must be the distance between two lines, not a point and a line. I want only real distances. I edited my original question to include some more specific ideas, such considering the outcome as a triangle. I would like to start by finding the shortest distance between the two lines that also passes through the origin, and this distance could be called the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The horizontal line $(HL)$ has equation $y=-b$ with $b>0$.

The vertical line $(VL)$ has equation $x=a$ with $a>0$

$A(-t,-b)$ is an arbitrary point on $HL$ in the third quadrant $(t>0)$

$B(a,y)$ is the point on $VL$ such that $B$ is in the first quadrant ($y>0$) and $AOB$ is a straight line where $O$ is the origin.

the slopes of $AO$ and $OB$ are equal so that $\frac{y}{a}=\frac{b}{t}$ and $y=\frac{a b}{t}$

we can now calculate the length of the hypotenuse

$\text{AB}=\sqrt{(a+t)^2+\left(\frac{a b}{t}+b\right)^2}=\frac{a+t}{t}\sqrt{t^2+b^2}$

The derivative of this function is equal to $\frac{t^3-a b^2}{t^2 \sqrt{t^2+b^2}}$

so the hypotenuse is minimal when $t=\sqrt[3]{a b^2}$ and

the shortest distance is given by $b\left(1+\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}$

**EDIT**:

a simpler form for the shortest distance: $\left(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}$

and the angle is given by $\tan  \theta = \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{1/3}$

Horizontal leg: $a^{1/3}\left(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}\right)$

Vertical leg :   $b^{1/3}\left(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}\right)$

Comment: This seems excellent, thank you. I will review this more in the next few days, but it seems to be what I needed for the next step in my problem. Is there a way to see the angle that this would create between the line HL and the shortest distance hypotenuse? The angle between HL and VL is 90 degrees, and your equation gives us the length of one side of the triangle (hypotenuse), so one more dimension is needed to solve all other dimensions of the triangle.

Comment: @user240834 I have edited my answer to include a more symmetric form for the shortest distance and also a formula to calculate the angle.

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose first that the two given lines are non-degenerate, i.e. they have the form $r_1: y=m_1 x + n_1$ and $r_2: y=m_2 x + n_2$, with $m_1,m_2 < \infty$. There is a third (unknown) line $r_3$, passing through the origin, with equation $y = mx$. If we had $m$ we could compute the intersection points $P_1$ and $P_1$, of $r_3$ with $r_1$ and $r_2$ as
$$x_1 = \frac{n_1}{m-m_1}, \; y_1 = m_1(\frac{n_1}{m-m_1}) + n_1$$
and 
$$x_2 = \frac{n_2}{m-m_2}, \; y_2 = m_2(\frac{n_2}{m-m_2}) + n_2.$$
Now, the Euclidean distance between $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is
$$d(P_1,P_2)=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2},$$
which we want to minimize. 
Then we just have to find the value of $m$ that minimizes $d(P_1,P_2)$. That involves computing the derivative of $d(P_1,P_2)$ with respect to $m$, equating the derivative with zero, and then solving for $m$.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work since one of the lines would be a straight vertical line. Could you show an example of how I would use this with the lines x=20, y=-15?